# SugarCRM: Use interactive javascript dialog with pre_execute file called by manifest

Tags: javascript, php, popup, manifest, sugarcrm

I am trying to create an interactive installer in SugarCRM where the pre_execute.php script called from the manifest.php file uses javascript to pop up a confirm dialog and from there, I feed the php script (via form) with the answer in order to maker decisions on what the script should do.

I have the (sample) pre_execute.php script working when it is NOT being called from the manifest file with the result of the pop-up dialog being properly reflected in the action the script takes after the user response.

I have the javascript pop-up confirm box being presented when the script is being called from the manifest file during installation, but the result of the pop-up dialog are NOT being reflected in the action the script takes after the user response.

And if I include a pop-up dialog in a script called from the manifest file, the module installation finishes and the page with "Display Log" appears for a brief second but is then replaced by a screen that shows only the following error message:

> Mode of operation not specified.

I call the pre_execute.php file from the manifest,php file using

```
'pre_execute' => array 
(
    0 =>  '<basepath>/scripts/pre_execute.php',
),
```

in the $installdefs array

In the pre_execute.php file I have 
(simple example to just create a file if the user clicks OK, or NOT create a file is the user clicks Cancel)

```
<?php

// This is a custom script which will be run once before the copy instructions are followed
echo "Made it to the start of the pre_execute script <br />.";

// Store the current page so that it can be refreshed during the javascript feed of the user response to the server php script
$pageURL = 'http';
if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") { $pageURL .= "s"; }
$pageURL .= "://";
if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80" && $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "443") 
{
    $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
}
else
{
    $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
}
echo "The url for this page is $pageURL <br />";

// Pop up a dialog box asking the user if they want to continue the installation
// If not, terminate the install
$message = "Do you want to continue the installation? Click on OK to continue, Cancel to terminate.";
echo "<form action=$pageURL method='post'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='answer' id='answer'>";
echo "</form>";
$java_code = <<<EOJS
<script type="text/javascript">
var alert_message = "$message";
var response = document.getElementById("answer");
response.value = confirm(alert_message);
response.form.submit();
exit();
</script>
EOJS;
if ( ! isset($_POST['answer']) )
{
    echo $java_code;
}
elseif ( $_POST['answer'] === 'false' )
{
    echo "The user response was ".$_POST['answer']." so the script terminated.<br />";
    die('User terminated installation');
}
else
{
    echo "The user response was ".$_POST['answer']." so the script will continue.<br />";
    // Create a new file with content (just to have something happen in this script)
    $created_file_name = '/var/www/html/crm/custom/custom_script_pre_execute_created_file.txt';
    $test_file_create = fopen($created_file_name,'x');
    $file_content = <<<EOF
This is the content
Put into the pre-execute file
by the script.
EOF;
    fwrite($test_file_create,$file_content);
    fclose($test_file_create);
    echo "The file $created_file_name has been created by the script. <br />";

    // Return to the calling file which included this file
    return;
}

?>
```

So, the real question is: How can I get a po-up dialog box to not only pop-up (which I have working) but to also have it so that:
- The user response is properly captured and acted on in the script ?
- The use of the pop-up dialog does NOT generate an error after the installation is complete ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the method of requesting and receiving/processing data within this pre_execute time is flawed, or at least more difficult than it needs to be. Would you consider a post_execute function that simply echo's a message and link to a configuration page? You can access the configuration page like `index.php?module=MyNewModule&action=config` (name your file config.php and drop it in your module's directory).

You can find an example of this in the open source SugarForge module JJWDesign Google Maps for SugarCRM http://www.sugarforge.org/projects/jjwgooglemaps/ (download the module directly at http://www.sugarforge.org/frs/download.php/11178/Google_Maps_v2.1.19_for_v6.zip).

The advantage is that now that you're on an actual page, you can more easily output your DHTML, and post data to the same page for processing.

Comment: Matthew,
Thank you for the feedback; you really know your stuff!
In my real application (which I did not put in order to simplify the question), I am hoping to use a pre_execute script to check for the existence of files (eg detailviewdefs in the custom directory to see if the user's installation has already had customizations done to it) and if so, present the user with an option to continue or terminate the installation.
In this scenario, I could not use the _post_install solution.
Is there a way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: If you want to adjust the detail|editviewdefs of a module upon installation, best practice is to just add your fields to the existing view. This can be done using the manifest $installdefs['layout_fields'] or if you want to add entire panels, see my previous answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/21458842/1769510. In general, you're going to have trouble checking for the existence of a custom file because Sugar's ModuleScanner prohibits file_exists and similar functions.

Comment: I am investigating your previous comments about adding panels.  Thank you for the feedback; I pretty much am working on this nights and weekends when possible so sometimes a delay in replying.  I do not understand the comment about file_exists.  I have created a pre_execute script, called from the manifest file, that has successfully detected the presence (or not) of a file using file_exists and I have successfully created edited and deleted files from the pre-execute script.  I much prefer the route of using Sugar's built in function if I can but looking at all options right now.

Comment: So, for the option of using the pre_execute script (and for general curiosity now for potential future use), I am still trying to determine if I can terminate the installation from within a manifest-called pre_execute script.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Adding to the above post, I am OK to call to javascript pop-up and act on the answer from either the pre_execute.php script called from the manifest file OR from the pre_install.php script included by Sugar.  I had previously thought they were equivalent but am finding out differently so either would server the purpose.