# How to add custom javascript code to validate field in contacts module in sugarcrm

Tags: sugarcrm

I want custom code to be made on onblur of first_name field in sugarcrm.
The code should also be upgrade safe.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Copy modules/Contacts/metadata/editviewdefs.php

into

custom/modules/Contacts/metadata/editviewdefs.php
(if it does not already exist. If so, use the existing one)

All your changes in this file are upgrade safe. Now open your new file, and you'll see one big array containing everything that's in the EditView of the Contacts-module.
Add the following inside the "templateMeta" array, for instance, right after "form".

```
'includes'=> array(
    array('file'=>'custom/modules/Contacts/EditView.js'),
),
```

This includes the file custom/modules/Contacts/EditView.js, in which you are free to write all the javascript you feel like!

Remember to do a Quick Repair & Rebuild when you are done.

Comment: What if I create an installable package(addon) and custom/modules/Contacts/metadata/editviewdefs.php already exists?Will it be upgrade safe?

Comment: No, it would overwrite the existing file if one exists. You should look into using post_execute and using ParserFactory to manipulate the existing view definitions, as discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21444143/adding-panels-to-editviewdefs-php-via-manifest-file/ -- Instead of working with $parser->_viewdefs [ 'panels' ] you'd be after $parser->_viewdefs [ 'templateMeta' ]['includes'] and simply add your  array('file'=>'custom/modules/Contacts/EditView.js'), to the existing array if it exists.

Comment: Can you please explain with code.Sorry but I am a Beginner.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of SugarCRM you uses, but in SugarCRM 7, the following works:

Create a file 'record.js' in /custom/modules/Contacts/clients/base/views/record/. In that file, you can add custom validation.

Some code you could use is:

```
({
    extendsFrom: 'YourModuleRecordView',
    initialize: function (options) {

        app.error.errorName2Keys['field_error'] = 'This is an error message';

        this._super('initialize', [options]);
        this.model.addValidationTask('check_field', _.bind(this._doValidateField, this));
    },
    _doValidateField: function(fields, errors, callback) {
        if (this.model.get('myField') .... ) {
            errors['myField'] = errors['myField'] || {};
            errors['myField'].field_error = true;
        }

        callback(null, fields, errors);
    }
});
```

Don't forget to change the fields names like you named them!
This result is only for edit mode. To add this validation to the creation mode, add the file 'create_actions.js' to /custom/modules/Contacts/clients/base/views/create_actions/

Enter the folling code in your 'create_actions.js':

```
({
    extendsFrom: 'CreateActionsView',
    initialize: function (options) {

        app.error.errorName2Keys['field_error'] = 'Thsis is an error message';

        this._super('initialize', [options]);
        this.model.addValidationTask('check_field', _.bind(this._doValidateField, this));
    },
    _doValidateField: function(fields, errors, callback) {
        if (.....) {
            errors['myField'] = errors['myField'] || {};
            errors['myField'].field_error = true;
        }

        callback(null, fields, errors);
    }
});
```

Perform a repair/rebuild when you added this files with the right code.
You can customize this code to your own needs.

Comment: How can we apply same validation for mobile view field?