# How to call a custom code on onblur event of first_name field?

Tags: sugarcrm

I have to create an addon (installable package) for SugarCRM that will call a custom JavaScript onblur of first_name element in Contacts module.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

See [SugarCRM Customization: Utilizing Custom JavaScript by Angel Magaña](http://cheleguanaco.blogspot.com/2012/08/sugarcrm-customization-utilizing-custom.html) for a quick tutorial on adding JavaScript to SugarCRM screens.

Once you have the code written and working, you can package it. Please review [SugarCRM's documentation about Module Loader](http://support.sugarcrm.com/04_Find_Answers/03_Developers/Module_Loader) to get general information about packaging your custom code.

In this case, you'll be tempted to package your `editviewdefs.php` but don't do it. Instead, use a `post_install.php` script with your package and manipulate the view using the ParserFacotry class, more information on that here: [Adding panels to editviewdefs.php via manifest file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21444143/adding-panels-to-editviewdefs-php-via-manifest-file/21458842#21458842)

Comment: I followed  SugarCRM Customization: Utilizing Custom JavaScript by Angel Magaña but that removes all customizations made.The package just replaces custom/modules/Contacts/metadata/editviewdefs.php.What if I have already this file?Please help.

Comment: Did you install that old phone number formatting module? Angel's instructions were clear: "We will not be installing the module, just examining some files. Thus, simply download the most current version of the module and do not concern yourself with the version of SugarCRM you are using." It was meant to be used as a case study and example.

Comment: But I actually need to create an installation package that do not overwrite any customizations.

Comment: Then read the second and third paragraphs of my answer. I explained to not copy in the editviewdefs but instead to manipulate the view via a script, and gave you an example.